# Paragraph separator as line terminator

Tags: javascript

The Javascript specification specifies four kinds of line terminators.

`LF`, `CR`, `line separator` and `paragraph separator`.

http://es5.github.com/#x7.3

Which of the above best describes the line separator used for the below snippet?

```
var char_count=0
var in_valid = "_!@#$%^&*()=+~`,<.>/?:;{[}]-|\\"
```

Comment: There's a `LF` between `0` and `v`...  I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be misinterpreting that section of the spec.

All of the line terminator characters are equivalent to each other. It doesn't matter which one is the separator for those two lines of code, any separator will have the same effect.

If you wrote the code on Windows, your original code probably has both CR and LF terminators. If you wrote it on mac or linux, it probably just has LF.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the first line is a "CR" and a "LF" in that order (although it may appear different to each viewer depending on their computer).

To see it, I used notepad++ and in the "View->Show Symbols" menu I hit "show all symbols". It shows you all the line feeds and carriage returns.

However, we commonly have a semi-colon at the end of a JavaScript statement.

Comment: There isn't actually a `CR` sent over the wire; Windows is adding that in when you copy to the clipboard.

Comment: True, but it's also possible that when he uploaded the form he was on a Mac but the form was interpreted by Linux. It's hard to know what the original line terminator really was.